# How to remove or improve :focus style on Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I did a carousel with bootstrap but the ":focus" doesn't work well.

Look at this bootply : http://www.bootply.com/iGyjdSSrhC

If you click on the chevron "Next" it will stay "white" (as Hovered). This is due the :focus style that is the same as the :hover.

I tried to change the :focus to put the same as non-hovered but after that it doesn't change on hover...

I think the button doesn't "reset" itself and thinks it is focused all the time. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the element will change on hover but if it was focused it will not change on hover because when you changed the :focus it overwrite the old style so you need to add style on focus+hover and it will work fine

```
.carousel-control:focus {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-control:focus:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/81ggxbo3/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap class is :

```
.carousel-control.right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.5)));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Just delete line `background-image` in bootstrap.css

Edit :

Do the same for control-left

and set that as :

```
.carousel-control.right:hover {
background-color: red;
    }
```

for example...

Comment: I don't really want to touch the initial Bootstrap css. And the background is not the problem. It's only when it's focused (the opacity: .9; doesn't change due the focus)

Comment: What opacity do you want to set?

Comment: Add this on your css : .carousel-control:focus{
 opacity: 0.5 !important;
}